# OAuth detecting whether User or Client Credentials are being used

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

As an example, let's say I create an endpoint `/car/[id]/upgrade-wheels`. The user can decide to upgrade their wheels through the website, or call customer services to upgrade the wheels though the CS App.

Therefore, this endpoint can be hit using both user and client credentials.

My question is, can I detect whether the creds being used are user or client creds? Then I can do something like:

```
if (userCreds)
{
    checkUserOwnsCar();
}
```

Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: Do you get the info of the user which is calling this API from token or something?

Comment: Token issued for a `client_credentials` grant usually doesn't have `sub` claim, or it's set to `client_id`.

Comment: Are you the one issuing tokens / do you have access to IdentityServer? If so you can add a specific claim for users/clients (or there might already be one) and check for its existence.

Comment: I do have a claim for users, so I could do something silly like 
if (!myClaim.?User) then checkUserOwnsCar();
But I was wondering whether there was a better way.